# Discord.py v1.0 How to retrieve every message from a channel and delete them one by one

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I have a `clear` command setup and the idea was to delete every message in a channel which I have the name hard-coded, but since I read that the method only deletes messages newer than 14 days I figured I'd have to somehow manually retrieve all the messages and then delete each one of them with the `delete` method.
I looked around but every example is either from before v1.0 or doesn't use commands with context the way I do.

Code:

```py
@self.discord_bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.channel != self.channel_name:
            return

        # clear history
        # retrieve messages using context ctx
        # for each loop that deletes them with self.discord_bot.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.trigger_typing()
        await ctx.send("Oops something happened! %s" % str(e))
        return
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using [`channel.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge). This will delete every message in the specified channel if the bot account has sufficient permissions.

```
@self.discord_bot.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    try:
        if ctx.channel != self.channel_name:
            return

        # clear history
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=None)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.trigger_typing()
        await ctx.send("Oops something happened! %s" % str(e))
        return
```